# tikzpicture polar plot with negative function values

Tags: tikz-pgf, polarplot

how to make similar polar plot to [Creating a Polar Grid with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169624/creating-a-polar-grid-with-tikz) -just using tikzp. (no pgfplots, pstricks etc)- with negative axis value, there  all example just start with axis 0.

So basically I want plot data from csv file with negative value level just using the tikz package.

similar question is [Negative y value in polar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145973/negative-y-value-in-polar-plot/145979#145979), with no package restriction

thanks.

Comment: Here's a solution that uses PGFPlots: [Negative y value in polar plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145979/2552)

Comment: Hi jake, thank you for your prompt reply. However, would be possible to get the same thing without using the pgfplots package?

Comment: Yes, see the answer to this question: [Creating a Polar Grid with Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169624/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno, Hi, do you refer to mr Paul Gessler on datavisualization comments? BTW, I haven't  found any answer to my question there.

Comment: Doing this without `pgfplots` isn't really wise or helpful. `pgfplots` is implemented with Ti*k*Z; I don't see the disadvantage in using it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments. So How can i get something similar to this http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-to-find-the-front-to-back-ratio-given-an-antenna-radiation-pattern-diagram in latex

Comment: If you want your axis to start from -10 for example, you can add 10 to all your values (in a `foreach` loop you can use `evaluate` for this), draw them and on the axis add the ticks -10,-9, ... in place of 0,1, ...

Comment: @Kpym,
thank you for you answer. 
    so now I m facing the following issue .. how to plot  polar data file inside the tikzpicture using the following statement, but I got a Cartesian instead of  polar one, \draw[color=blue, domain=0:360, line width=1.5pt] plot[smooth] file {data.dat};  % data.dat {
0 8.381467
45 9.090974
90 9.877479
135 10.68895
180 11.49293
225 12.27133
270 13.0153
325 13.72148
360 8.381467}

Comment: @mark sorry I don't understand your question, but if it is not anymore about polar plot with negative function values, please post another question.